# Spring file configuration with conditions

Tags: java, spring, cxf

In my spring configuration I am loading a file with all the cxf services when I start a test. Sometimes, I don't want load these services on my tests because aren't necessary and I want work quickly.

I have all my cxf services loaded in this way:

```
<import resource="classpath:services-app-ib-es-test.xml" />
```

Can I change this line to read it only on conditional way? Something like this:

```
<if javavm param loadcxf = true>
    <import resource="classpath:services-app-ib-es-test.xml" />
</if>
```

**Edit**: I am using spring-core-2.55

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

With Spring 3.1 you could use the `Profile` feature, giving the profile as JM argument or in a property file.

I don't know about spring 2.x.

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/new-in-3.1.html

http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/14/spring-3-1-m1-introducing-profile/

http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/